# Windows 10 Enterprise will expire soon

Tags: windows-10

My PC came with Windows 10 Enterprise edition preinstalled and now I get a message that 'Windows license will expire soon'.

I have tried rearming (slmgr .vbs /rearm) and restarting and changing group policy but still no results and I cannot contact the store that I bought the PC from.

- I am reading that it is possible to downgrade to Windows 10 Pro by getting a license key for Pro and changing keys
- I have also read that if I let the license expire it will automatically downgrade to Pro

I have no idea if the above things I have mentioned can be done.

What are my options here and what can I do?

NOTE: I really want to avoid formatting and clean install since it took me ages to set up this PC (it is used for music production)

Comment: Buy Pro key and change it?

Comment: @IGRACH is it possible? Because half the sites I read say it is and the other half say it isn't... Have you done this and can confirm that it works?

Comment: No. But you could send mail to Microsoft Support with this explanation and they will advise you.

Comment: @IGRACH - Microsoft does not provide help by email.

Comment: "I have also read that if I let the license expire it will automatically downgrade to Pro" - When the license expires, the installation will be unlicensed, what you describe absolutely does not happen. You won't be able to activate your license without a KMS. Windows 10 Enterprise installations, which can only be licenses with a volume license, must communicate with a valid KMS every 90 days. Based on what you describe, the machine came with an unlicensed Windows 10 Enterprise installation, you should reinstall Windows 10 Home and/or Windows 10 Professional. Your installation is not legitimate

Comment: first… Yell at the scammers who sold you a hooky copy of Enterprise - which **must** be able to see its key-server every couple of months - & get them to give you a proper key for Pro. You can then change it with no penalty from Update & Security>Activation>Change product key.

Comment: @Tetsujin - If there is an existing answer that explains how to downgrade Enterprise to Professional I cannot find it.  The only question I can find, has a comment, where I suggested somebody submit a similar answer.  My point is that we need an answer that explains how to downgrade Enterprise to Professional.

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't even need Enterprise! Home was good enough for me. So If I get them to give me or buy a Pro key myself, will I be able to change the key and continue to Pro without formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically [though I have never attempted this] you can downgrade Windows 10 Enterprise to Pro by changing the Product Key.

From [Apes With Computers - Downgrade Windows 10 Enterprise to Professional](https://www.apeswithcomputers.com/article/downgrade-windows-10-enterprise-to-professional)

> 1. Open the Settings app and click Update & Security.
> 2. Open Activation and click Change product key.
> 3. Enter your Windows 10 Professional product key and click Next.
> 4. Restart the computer after the new product key is activated.
>
> You can force a downgrade with the default product key (VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T) of Windows 10 Professional, however this will not activate Windows.

Note this can only be done with Enterprise to Pro, you cannot downgrade Enterprise to Home.

Comment: Just to confirm. I got a Pro key and changed the activation key to it and I got a seemless downgrade to Windows Pro! I am very happy because I didn't lose any data!